# find all numbers that appear at least three times consecutively

Tags: mysql

[image]

This is a question from leetcode online judge

I tried this

```
SELECT Num FROM Logs GROUP BY Num HAVING COUNT (Num) >1
```

but got runtime error!!

Anyhelp would be appreciated

Comment: DBA.SE Community. Please don't close this. This question is not as trivial as it appears. I also supplied an answer that is not trivial.

Comment: What if there are gaps in the ids? Say we have 3 rows with `(1,1), (2,1), (4,1)`. Would that count as a consecutive 3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, your runtime error is based on `COUNT (Num)`. It should be `COUNT(Num)`

## SAMPLE DATA

```
mysql> DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS guru;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE DATABASE guru;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> USE guru
Database changed
mysql> CREATE TABLE logs
    -> (id int not null auto_increment,
    -> num int not null,
    -> primary key (id));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO logs (num) VALUES (1),(1),(1),(2),(1),(2),(2);
Query OK, 7 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 7  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM logs;
+----+-----+
| id | num |
+----+-----+
|  1 |   1 |
|  2 |   1 |
|  3 |   1 |
|  4 |   2 |
|  5 |   1 |
|  6 |   2 |
|  7 |   2 |
+----+-----+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

## YOUR QUERY EXECUTED

```
mysql> SELECT Num FROM Logs GROUP BY Num HAVING COUNT(Num) > 1;
+-----+
| Num |
+-----+
|   1 |
|   2 |
+-----+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

## LOOK AT THE QUESTION AGAIN

```
Write a SQL query to find all numbers that appear at least three times consecutively
```

From the output in your question, `2` does not occur three times consecutively.

I have an iterative solution using user-defined variables

## MY PROPOSED QUERY

```
SET @curnum = -999;
SET @same = 1;
SET @group = 0;
SELECT DISTINCT num FROM
(
    SELECT grp,num,MAX(samecount) same FROM
    (
        SELECT
            (@group := @group + IF(@curnum=num,0,1)) grp,
            (@same  := IF(@curnum=num,@same+1,1)) samecount,
            (@curnum:=num),num
        FROM logs ORDER BY id
    ) AA GROUP BY grp,num HAVING same >= 3
) A;
```

Looks messy, right ? Here is is executed

## MY PROPOSED QUERY EXECUTED

```
mysql> SET @curnum = -999;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET @same = 1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET @group = 0;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT DISTINCT num FROM
    -> (
    ->     SELECT grp,num,MAX(samecount) same FROM
    ->     (
    ->         SELECT
    ->             (@group := @group + IF(@curnum=num,0,1)) grp,
    ->             (@same  := IF(@curnum=num,@same+1,1)) samecount,
    ->             (@curnum:=num),num
    ->         FROM logs ORDER BY id
    ->     ) AA GROUP BY grp,num HAVING same >= 3
    -> ) A;
+-----+
| num |
+-----+
|   1 |
+-----+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql>
```

## WHY IT WORKS

Let's strip all the aggregation and subquery stuff and start with the innermost query

```
SET @curnum = -999;
SET @same = 1;
SET @group = 0;
SELECT
    (@group := @group + IF(@curnum=num,0,1)) grp,
    (@same  := IF(@curnum=num,@same+1,1)) samecount,
    (@curnum:=num),num
FROM logs ORDER BY id;
```

When you run this, here is the output

```
mysql> SET @curnum = -999;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET @same = 1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET @group = 0;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT
    ->     (@group := @group + IF(@curnum=num,0,1)) grp,
    ->     (@same  := IF(@curnum=num,@same+1,1)) samecount,
    ->     (@curnum:=num),num
    -> FROM logs ORDER BY id
    -> ;
+------+-----------+----------------+-----+
| grp  | samecount | (@curnum:=num) | num |
+------+-----------+----------------+-----+
|    1 |         1 |              1 |   1 |
|    1 |         2 |              1 |   1 |
|    1 |         3 |              1 |   1 |
|    2 |         1 |              2 |   2 |
|    3 |         1 |              1 |   1 |
|    4 |         1 |              2 |   2 |
|    4 |         2 |              2 |   2 |
+------+-----------+----------------+-----+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Note the column `samecount`. When `samecount` reaches 3 or more, the `num` column has the value that has been repeated 3 or more times.

Adding the aggregation layer, you get this:

```
mysql> SET @curnum = -999;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET @same = 1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET @group = 0;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT grp,num,MAX(samecount) same FROM
    -> (
    ->     SELECT
    ->         (@group := @group + IF(@curnum=num,0,1)) grp,
    ->         (@same  := IF(@curnum=num,@same+1,1)) samecount,
    ->         (@curnum:=num),num
    ->     FROM logs ORDER BY id
    -> ) AA GROUP BY grp,num HAVING same >= 3;
+------+-----+------+
| grp  | num | same |
+------+-----+------+
|    1 |   1 |    3 |
+------+-----+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

After the aggregation, it is possible that a number can be repeated multiple times later on.

Adding the DISTINCT layer on just NUM, you get the end result I said before.

## QUERY AGAINST MORE DATA

Let's add more data

```
INSERT INTO logs (num) VALUES (1),(1),(1),(2),(1),(2),(2);
INSERT INTO logs (num) VALUES (7),(7),(7),(8),(8),(9),(5);
INSERT INTO logs (num) VALUES (5),(6),(11),(11),(11),(2),(2);
INSERT INTO logs (num) VALUES (4),(4),(4),(4),(4),(3),(3);
INSERT INTO logs (num) VALUES (1),(1),(1),(2),(1),(2),(2);
```

## MY PROPOSED QUERY EXECUTED WITH MORE DATA

```
mysql> SET @curnum = -999;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET @same = 1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET @group = 0;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT DISTINCT num FROM
    -> (
    ->     SELECT grp,num,MAX(samecount) same FROM
    ->     (
    ->         SELECT
    ->             (@group := @group + IF(@curnum=num,0,1)) grp,
    ->             (@same  := IF(@curnum=num,@same+1,1)) samecount,
    ->             (@curnum:=num),num
    ->         FROM logs ORDER BY id
    ->     ) AA GROUP BY grp,num HAVING same >= 3
    -> ) A;
+-----+
| num |
+-----+
|   1 |
|   7 |
|  11 |
|   4 |
+-----+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!

Answer (score 2):

Found a similar question asked here: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic911571-338-1.aspx. Adapting the solution posted in that url, I got the following. Give it a try:

**EDIT. Disclaimer:** This works on SQL Server 2008 R2. Did not notice the MySql tag. If you are not on a **DBMS that has windowed aggregates**, disregard.

**Setup test table from your data:**

```
Declare @tbl Table
(
       Id int,
       Num int
)

Insert into @tbl 
          select '1','1'
union all select '2','1'
union all select '3','1'
union all select '4','2'
union all select '5','1'
union all select '6','2'
union all select '7','2'
select * from @tbl
```

**Query for the above table data:**

```
DECLARE @cnt INT
SET @cnt = 3

SELECT
  Id, Num
FROM
(
  SELECT
      Id, Num, groupID, 
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY   Num, groupID) AS groupCnt
  FROM
  (
    SELECT
      Id, Num,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY Id)
      - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Num ORDER BY Id) AS groupID
    FROM
      @tbl
  ) T1
) T2
WHERE
   groupCnt >= @cnt
ORDER BY
   Id
```

Comment: MySql doesn't support windowed aggregates.

Comment: Opps. Thank for pointing that out. I have added the disclaimer.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT l1.Num As ConsecutiveNums
FROM Logs l1, Logs l2, Logs l3
WHERE l1.Num = l2.Num 
    AND l2.Num = l3.Num 
    AND l1.Id = l2.Id + 1 
    AND l2.Id = l3.Id + 1;
```

Comment: I just tried you query against the sample data from my answer (http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/89499/877). Guess what? IT WORKS !!! The output was `1,7,11,4` just like my answer. +1 for you today, and Welcome to the DBA StackExchange.

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA Right. It will work but only if the `id` values have no gaps.

Answer (score 1):

Just another simple way but not recommended.

> ```
> SELECT DISTINCT
>     l1.Num AS ConsecutiveNums
> FROM
>     Logs l1,
>     Logs l2,
>     Logs l3
> WHERE
>     l1.Id = l2.Id - 1
>     AND l2.Id = l3.Id - 1
>     AND l1.Num = l2.Num
>     AND l2.Num = l3.Num
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
SET @n = 3 - 1; 
SELECT c.Num ConsecutiveNums FROM (
   SELECT r.Num Num, count(r.Num) count FROM (
   SELECT Num,    
   LEAD(Num) OVER(ORDER BY Id) as "next",    
   LAG(Num) OVER(ORDER BY Id) as previous FROM Num ) r 
WHERE (r.Num = r.next) AND (r.Num = r.previous) group by r.Num ) c 
WHERE c.count >= @n;
```

Comment: please add always some explanation to your code

Answer (score 0):

This question was asked in 2015, back when window functions were not a feature in MySQL. However the current versions of MySQL support these functions (after being introduced in version 8.0).

So, if anyone is seeking a solution in MySQL using window functions, the following query will work.

```
Select distinct(Num) as ConsecutiveNums
from (select Num,
      lag(Num) over (order by Id) as pre,   
      lead(Num) over (order by Id) as pro
      from Logs) n
      where pre = num and num = pro;
```

Passed all tests on leetcode as well. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
with cte as 
(

SELECT 1 id, 1 num from dual union all
SELECT 2 id, 1 num from dual union all
SELECT 3 id, 1 num from dual union all
SELECT 4 id, 2 num from dual union all
SELECT 5 id, 1 num from dual union all
SELECT 6 id, 2 num from dual union all
SELECT 7 id, 2 num from dual)
select grp,num from (
select id, num,
row_number() over(partition by num order by id) rn2,
id - row_number() over(partition by num order by id) grp
 from cte
 )
 group by grp,num
 having count(distinct id) >=3
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select distinct(a.Num) as ConsecutiveNums 
from Logs a, Logs b,Logs c 
where a.Id=b.Id+1 and a.Num=b.Num 
and b.Id=c.Id+1 and b.Num=c.Num
```

From https://discuss.leetcode.com/topic/22606/simple-solution

Comment: Why the parentheses? `DISTINCT` is not a function.

Comment: Maybe you found this elsewhere but the query is essentially identical to [Vinny's solution](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/93144/6965) in this same thread (my point being, your answer isn't adding any new value).